# Необходимо достать дубликаты

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Коллеги, доброго времени суток.
Есть 2 датафрейма за 2 месяца, имеющие данные юзера, необходимо эти 2 датафрейма сравнить и найти юзеров, которые повторяются в 2 месяцах.
На данный момент оставил только необходимый столбец и вроде как создал новый столбец со значением(повторяется или нет).
Ссылка на исходные [данные](https://dropmefiles.com/xYYrb)

```
m = (october.merge(november, how='outer', on=['Структурная единица'], 
          suffixes=['', '_new'], indicator=True))
```

| Структурная единица | _merge |
| --- | --- |
| 0 Клиент | both |
| 1 ЦСО Тверь | both |
| 2 1760 | left_only |
| 3 1760 | left_only |
| 4 6251 | left_only |
| ... | ... |
| 23984 | Яшкевич Валерий Олегович |
| 23985 | яшкевич вероника |
| 23986 | яшкевич николай |
| 23987 | Яшов Захар Денисович |
| 23988 | Яшова Надия Мусхатовна right_only |

23989 rows × 2 columns

Ещё прикрепляю скриншот таблицы для наглядности, а то не получилось сделать таблицу такой же:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как я могу вывести в отдельный датафрейм всех повторяющихся пользователей и их
количество?

Comment: Приведённые данные не очень соответствуют коду и описанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, что необходимо найти совпадения по пользователю и общее количество повторений этого пользователя в двух датафреймах, то подойдёт функция с использованием [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) и [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
def user_counts(df1, df2, column):
    return (df1[df1[column].isin(df2[column])][column].value_counts() +
            df2[df2[column].isin(df1[column])][column].value_counts()).reset_index()

user_counts(october, november, 'Структурная единица')
```

Вывод:

```
    Структурная единица count
0   Абаканов Савелий Андреевич  2
1   Абасов Эмиль    2
2   Абашин Роман Владимирович   3
3   Аббасова Диана Дмитриевна   4
4   Абдулин 2
... ... ...
2245    тимофеева алиса николаевна  2
2246    федорова александра андреевна   3
2247    школьников юрий олеговвич   4
2248    шувалов федор александрович 3
2249    янглеев данила артемович    2

2250 rows × 2 columns
```

Comment: Очень наглядно выдается инфа, спасибо большое за такой классный способ, то, что было нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен перечень уникальных ФИО, которые встречаются и в первом и во втором фрейме, то так:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Структурная единица', how='inner')['Структурная единица'].drop_duplicates()
```

Индикатор здесь лишний, достаточно применить аргумент `how='inner'`. Потом удалить дубликаты.

Comment: Крутой код, спасибо за поправку, работает!